# SyndicationFeed output is not recognized by Internet Explorer 8 rss

Tags: .net, internet-explorer-8, rss

I'm using the .net `SyndicationFeed` to write out feed to an xml file.  Here's the output of `SaveAsRss20`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <description>My Feed Description</description>
    <item>
      <author>notAnEmail@notAHost.com</author>
      <category>Good</category>
      <title>The big story</title>
      <description>The big story content</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 11 Apr 2012 14:49:46 -0400</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <author>notAnEmail@notAHost.com</author>
      <category>Bad</category>
      <title>Small news</title>
      <description>Small news content</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 11 Apr 2012 14:49:46 -0400</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <author>notAnEmail@notAHost.com</author>
      <category>Bad</category>
      <category>Good</category>
      <title>Birthday announcements</title>
      <description>Birthday announcements content</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 11 Apr 2012 14:49:46 -0400</pubDate>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

The feed opens as an xml file in Internet Explorer 8 - it does not get the xslt treatment that other feed xml files get.

I've also tried `SaveAsAtom10` which leads to different xml, but same IE8 behavior.

My co-worker says that he is able to subscribe to the feed with another feedreader, but my feedreader of choice is IE8, so I'd like to get my feeds to work with it.

What am I missing to get the feed recognized by IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Response Type is: application/rss+xml

I know I've had similar issues with IE and feeds, with the cause typically being the response type.